# Applying xml style to the button on code. No error message, but no style either

Tags: android, button, dynamic, styles

I am trying to give the style for a code-created button. The file style has following lines.

```
<style name="buttonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#33B5E5</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

Now I am doing as

```
    nextpersonbtn = new Button(this, null, R.style.buttonStyle);
    nextpersonbtn.setText("Second person");
```

No error message in logcat. Program runs well in emulator. But the button doesnt have any style. Not even its default style. The test "Second person" is standing like a textview. 
Can anybody please suggest what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Have you put your <style> within <resources>? Have you put your xml file in the right folder (values)?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani, yes. Its in right folder.

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you're trying works only for API 11 and up. Alternatively you could create thr button in an xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"/>
```

And use apply it to a button like:

```
Button nextpersonbtn = (Button)  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_button, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works only from API Level 11

for api below 11
 I would suggest you to Define your Button as an XML with all the styling you want and simply inflate that XML to an object inside your code.